# How to sort file or folder by filename or date at ascending or descending in Android?

Tags: android, file, sorting, filesort

The following sample code is from Internet, I hope to sort `the List<String> files` by filename at ascending or descending.
I hope to the L`ist<String> files` by date of file at ascending or descending, how can I do ? Thanks!

The same quetsion with `List<String> directories`.

```
  List<String> files = Arrays.asList(f.list(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            File f=new File(dir, name);               

            return f.isFile()&&(f.isHidden()==false);
        }
    }));
    Collections.sort(files);




List<String> directories = Arrays.asList(f.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        File f=new File(dir, name);
        return f.isDirectory()&& (f.isHidden()==false);
    }
}));
Collections.sort(directories);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just provide your File array and it sort simple.

```
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        return Long.compare(f1.lastModified(), f2.lastModified());
    }
});
```

**Demo:**

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/DCIM/Camera");
        File[] filesList = path.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < filesList.length; i++) {
            Date lastModDate = new Date(filesList[i].lastModified());
            Log.i("Pre sorted", "File last modified @ : " + lastModDate.toString());
        }

        Arrays.sort(filesList, new Comparator<File>() {
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                return Long.compare(f1.lastModified(), f2.lastModified());
            }
        });
        Log.i("sorted", "----------------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < filesList.length; i++) {
            Date lastModDate = new Date(filesList[i].lastModified());
            Log.i("Pro sorted", "File last modified @ : " + lastModDate.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.util.Comparator<java.io.File>', required: 'java.util.Comparator<? super java.lang.Object>'

Comment: Do I need to add @Override before public int compare(File f1, File f2)  in your code?

Comment: Note for Descending Order Change Long.compare(f1.lastModified(), f2.lastModified()); into Long.compare(f2.lastModified(), f1.lastModified()); . Switch over f1 and f2.

Answer (score 3):

You can use like below for sorting based on file name and change that value for date and other comparision. Or simply use [ApacheCommons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/comparator/package-summary.html), it will give direct APIs

```
File[] directoryList = currentFolder.listFiles(); 
if (directoryList != null) {
   List<File> directoryListing = new ArrayList<File>();
   directoryListing.addAll(Arrays.asList(directoryList));
   Collections.sort(directoryListing, new SortFileName());
   Collections.sort(directoryListing, new SortFolder());
}


//sorts based on the files name
public class SortFileName implements Comparator<File> {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
          return f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName());
    }
}

//sorts based on a file or folder. folders will be listed first
public class SortFolder implements Comparator<File> {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
         if (f1.isDirectory() == f2.isDirectory())
            return 0;
         else if (f1.isDirectory() && !f2.isDirectory())
            return -1;
         else
            return 1;
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be late to answer bt this method sort files by desc order by modified date

```
File[] listFile = dir.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(listFile, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                return Long.compare(o2.lastModified(), o1.lastModified());
            }
        });
```